# Join tables and Count participants in the past

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have participants that have multiple orders.  I can easily find counts of orders in the past but have to use a join to count participants in the past.  The code I am using does not give me correct numbers.  The code is :

```
select count(distinct o.participant_id)
from dbaq.participant p, dbaq.orders o 
where o.participant_id=p.participant_id and
      (p.water_staff=1) and p.active = '1' and
      date_part('year', o.order_date) = 2018;
```

I figured out why this is not going to work ... the number of active participants goes down when I look at each subsequent year in the past ... becasue they are leaving and no longer active.  I don't think there is a way to track who was active in the past.  Thanks for your input though - great suggestions below.

Comment: Have you ever heard of `JOIN`?  You should use it.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to find the number of participants for an active order in this year. Am I right? If yes you could try

```
 SELECT   o.participant_id,
    COUNT(*)
  FROM dbaq.participant p,
    dbaq.orders o
  WHERE o.participant_id                = p.participant_id
    AND p.water_staff                   = 1
    AND p.active                        = '1'
    AND extract(YEAR FROM o.order_date) = '2018'
    group by o.participant_id;
```

Comment: Interesting ... this gives me the same total as before but lists each participant ID and it appears how many bottles they ordered. Actually I am trying to count how many participants there have been in previous years as well. Still has the incorrect answer ... I think what might be happening ... orders from each year in the past are not being counted because those people are not active any longer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT o.participant_id)
FROM 
    dbaq.orders o
JOIN
    dbaq.participant p
ON
    o.participant_id = p.participant_id
WHERE
    p.water_staff = 1 
AND
    p.active = '1' 
AND
    DATE_PART('year', o.order_date) = 2018;
```

Comment: gives me the same answer as before. Thanks though!